# Get Balance of an Addaptive account

Tags: paypal

Paypal Addaptive Account/Payment APIs don't offer any methods to retrieve their balance. Is this possible via GetBalance from the Merchant API?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `GetFundingPlans` which is part of Adaptive Payments API:

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/GetFundingPlans_API_Operation/

However, this is only allowed to be called on implicitly (you have to be the sender and caller of the API.) If you wish to get other peoples balance you need to use the Classic API call `GetBalance`, and you would need to use the Permissions API to request permission first.